# The use of arrays in a recursive function in Dafny leads to verification failure

Tags: dafny

The following code, `assert f(arr, 2) == 0;`, fails to verify.

```
function f(bs:array<int>, hi:nat) : nat
{
  if hi==0 then 0 else f(bs, hi-1)
}

method Main() {
  var arr := new int[3][1, 1, 1];
  assert f(arr, 2) == 0;
}
```

Moreover, I found that:

- When I add a new hint `assert f(arr, 0) == 0;`, it can pass the verification.
- Or when I use a sequence (seq), it can also pass.

I really can't understand what the reason is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ordinarily, Dafny automatically unrolls a function once. That's enough to prove each of the first two assertions in your updated example. In most cases in verification, this is enough, because if you don't know the values of the parameters, the proofs are symbolic and usually done by induction in one form or another.

In the third assertion, function `f` needs to be unrolled 6 times in order to determine that the result value is 0. The verifier is not doing that automatically, so you have to help it along. For example, you could write the `Main` method as

```
method Main() {
  var arr := new int[5][1, 1, 1, 1, 1];
  assert f(arr, 0) == 0;
  assert forall i:: 0< i<=arr.Length ==> f(arr, i)==f(arr, i-1);
  calc {
    f(arr, arr.Length);
  ==  // by the definition of f
    f(arr, arr.Length - 1);
  ==
    f(arr, arr.Length - 2);
  ==
    f(arr, arr.Length - 3);
  ==
    f(arr, arr.Length - 4);
  ==
    f(arr, arr.Length - 5);
  ==
    0;
  }
  assert f(arr, arr.Length) == 0;
}
```

In general, this is what you'd need to do.

Advanced:

However, Dafny does actually help you out a little more. In some cases, it unrolls a function call twice, and in some cases, it can even continue unrolling the function until it stops. The latter happens when the parameters passed to the function are literals, or at least when the arguments that affect termination are literals. The `arr.Length` argument is known to equal the literal `5`, but the argument `arr` is not a literal. So, for starters, Dafny would need to be told that termination of `f` depends only on the `hi` argument, not on `bs`. By default, Dafny gives you `decreases bs, hi` for `f`, but if you write `decreases hi`, then Dafny will know that termination depends only on `hi`. This may still not work automatically with the array argument, but it does work if you use a sequence instead of an array. (Sequences may be easier, because they are value types.) For example, the following program verifies automatically:

```
function f(bs: seq<int>, hi: nat): nat
  requires hi <= |bs|
  decreases hi
{
  if hi == 0 then 0 else f(bs, hi - 1)
}

method Main() {
  var arr := new int[5][1, 1, 1, 1, 1];
  assert f(arr[..], 0) == 0;
  assert forall i :: 0 < i <= arr.Length ==> f(arr[..], i) == f(arr[..], i - 1);
  assert f(arr[..], arr.Length) == 0;
}
```

(If you're interested in the details of how this works, see https://leino.science/papers/krml237.pdf.)

So, the verifier *can* be more automatic in some cases, but I would still suggest keeping "the verifier unrolls each function call just once" in mind as a rule of thumb.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Dafny's documentation](https://dafny.org/dafny/OnlineTutorial/guide.html#termination):

> The other situation that requires a termination proof is when methods or functions are recursive. Similarly to looping forever, these methods could potentially call themselves forever, never returning to their original caller. When Dafny is not able to guess the termination condition, an explicit decreases clause can be given along with pre- and postconditions, as in the unnecessary annotation for the fib function:
>
> ```
> function fib(n: nat): nat
>   decreases n
> {
>   if n == 0 then 0
>   else if n == 1 then 1
>   else fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2)
> }
> ```
>
> **As before, Dafny can guess this condition on its own, but sometimes the decreasing condition is hidden within a field of an object or somewhere else where Dafny cannot find it on its own, and it requires an explicit annotation.**

So you can change your code to

```dart
function f(bs:array<int>, hi:nat) : nat
  decreases hi
{
  if hi==0 then 0 else f(bs, hi-1)
}

method Main() {
  var arr := new int[3][1, 1, 1];
  assert f(arr, 2) == 0;
}
```

for it to work.

Comment: Thanks! I've encountered a new problem. After I simply added `reads bs` on the second line, the verification failed again... Thanks again! (I don't know how to input a code block in the comment, it doesn't seem to automatically line wrap.)

Comment: I've pasted the code in the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

```
function f(bs:array<int>, hi:nat) : nat
  decreases hi
  requires 0 <= hi <= bs.Length
  requires bs.Length > 1
  reads bs

{
  if hi==0 then 0 else f(bs, hi-1)
}

method Main() {
  var arr := new int[5][1, 1, 1, 1, 1];
  assert f(arr, 0) == 0;
  assert forall i:: 0< i<=arr.Length ==> f(arr, i)==f(arr, i-1);
  assert f(arr, arr.Length) == 0;
}
```

assert f(arr, arr.Length) == 0; the verification failed..

@enzo

Comment: even `reads null`

Comment: Why are you @-mentioning enzo? Is this supposed to be an answer, or a reply of some kind? Please read [answer].